# Can I recite a SURAT after Faatihat in my 3rd and 4th rakat if i meet Imam in the 3rd rakat (which is my 1st rakat in this case) in ishai

Tags: salat

Thank you very much. If I meet imam in the 3rd Rakat (Ishai prayer-where 3rd and 4th rakats are only Faatihat rakats) and of course complete the 4th rakat with him. Now i have done only 2 rakats. To pray my 3rd and 4th rakats should i read Faatihat only (in the 3rd and 4th rakat respectively) or i should read surat after the Faatihat in the 3rd and also in the 4th rakat. Not reading surat beside faatihat in this case makes **all** my ishai rakats only "faatihat rakats". Is that OK?

Comment: Sorry, i believe i found the answer to my question under the title "Related", item no 7-summarized in these lines: "Since the first lost Rakat contain the verse reading after Fatiha, then while repeating your missed Rakat you read the verses, even if this was your 3rd Raka for ex."

Comment: The thing is that one just need to read over and over an explanation (thoroughly) before withdrawing. Ex.they used "verse" in place of "surat".I just wish members cross check spelling and other stuff before posting for ease of understanding. Thanks bros.

Comment: Some info here as well - http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/what-is-the-exact-manner-to-join-the-salat-jamat-after-arriving-late

Comment: This question could be **unclear, since no school mentioned which is highly necessary in this case**, and what is not clear in this possible duplicate of the question pointed out by mtk.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can recite the Surah Fatiha (only) in the third and fourth Rek’a (instead of Tasbihat al-Arba’a). (it doesn’t make any difference if you are in Salat-al-Jama’a or not). Hence you shall not recite another Surah … (in accordance with the ruling of Shia)

**According to the ruling of Imam Khomeini:**

> a person who says prayer, he/she can recite Surah al-Fatiha instead
>   of Tasihat al ara’a, but the point is that he ought to recite it
>   slowly (with the low voice) and it is Ehtiat-al-Wajib that he does not
>   recite the Bismillah-al-Rahmane-Rahim loudly (in the 3th and 4th
>   Rek’a)
>
> توضیح المسائل(المحشی للإمام الخمینی)  ج‏1ص 555   مسأله 1005
>
> (Tozih-Al-Masael (Al-Mahshi Lel Imam Khomein) Vol.1, Pg.555 M1005)

So in accordance with the mentioned issue, we can figure out that you ought not to recite another Surah after Surah Al Fatiha …

---

**Source**: [www.hawzah.net](http://www.hawzah.net/fa/question/questionview/11073)