# How should one finish his prayer if he joins the jamaat in the third or the fourth rakat?

Tags: salat, jamaat

If a man comes to the masjid and sees that the congregation has already started and they are at the third or the fourth rakat, should he join them or wait for another congregation?

Comment: I think how to join is well explained here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/what-is-the-exact-manner-to-join-the-salat-jamat-after-arriving-late and of course you should join a congregation even if you knew the Imam is at the last tahiyyat!