# If I miss congregation salah?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, fiqh, jamaat

Assalamuallaykum.
I used to miss my congregation's salah of zohr.
I leave my college and reach masjid to attend my zohr salah with jamat (in congregation), but the time for traveling is so long that I just miss my salah.

I reach masjid just 10 to 15 minutes late. Can I pray it alone and will it be accepted?

What niyah should I make while praying fard salah alone?

Comment: Please consider using relevant and significant tags!

Comment: Some relevant posts: [When coming too late to the mosque is it allowed to pray in a second congregation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37078/when-coming-too-late-to-the-mosque-is-it-allowed-to-pray-in-a-second-congregation), [Can niyat (intention) be done by heart, or must it be declared verbally?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40279/can-niyat-intention-be-done-by-heart-or-must-it-be-declared-verbally) and [What are the rules for reading 4 raka fard... alone](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23449/what-are-the-rules-for-reading-4-raka-fard-with-jamat-or-alone)

Answer (score 1):

**"I reach masjid just 10-15 min late. So can i pray it alone and will it be accepted?"**

As opposed to not praying? The prayer is obligatory on you, and you do not have to pray in congregation even though it has more merit than praying alone. I am sure you see many people praying by themselves when they are late in the mosques, so surely you can easily ask them and discuss there or talk to the Imam of the mosque.

The prayer also has a time-frame within which is it accepted. If you pray it within that time, it will be accepted, provided you have the other conditions of prayer like wudu etc. I would suggest you read some authentic scholarly works on prayer, because these basic questions should not be asked from strangers without doing your due diligence.

Answer (score 0):

Comitting Salah in congregation is not obligatory, but is highly encouraged, unless some specific situations arise that will make it obligatory. For example, if I can not pronounce the words in the Surahs recited in Salah correctly enough, then some scholars believe I should commit my Salah's in congregation, at least, as much as it is possible for me.

About how to commit Salah alone, you should first determine what sect you follow. There are some differences between how different sects do this, if I'm not wrong.