# According to the Hanafi school, how do you complete missed rakah in congregation prayer?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, hanafi

How do you complete missed rakah in congregation prayer.  I would like to know the rules according to the Hanafi school of thought, since it is  prevalent  in our region.

What I am aware of is that, if you are able to "join the prayer" before the imam gets up from the ruku position, then you have not missed that rakah. But what does it mean to "join the prayer". Can I join the prayer without reading thana, Ta'awwudh, tasmiyah, Al-faatiha and the additional surat? Are the rules of joining the prayer different for **non-silent** prayers such as fajr, magrib, isha?

Please explain all the situations i.e., if I join in 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th rakat for fajr, asr, magrib and isha prayers, since they involve different no of rakah and also because asr salah is silent.

Comment: A general how to can be found in [What is the exact manner to join the salat jamat after arriving late](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/what-is-the-exact-manner-to-join-the-salat-jamat-after-arriving-late) it is not specificly answered for the hanafi madhhab,

Comment: Thanks for the effort. From what i have come to know from my elders, they follow the same procedure, as given in the answer below.

Comment: This is how I've been taught to do it, and how I've seen other hanafis do it: You say the initial *takbir* and immediately adopt the Imam's posture. If you bowed in *rukuh* before the Imam rises from it, you have caught that *rakah*, and are exempted from the *qirat*. At the end you say *tashahhud* and then remain silent; you do not say the *salawat* (durood) nor the *dua*. When the Imam says the *taslim* you remain still, when he finishes you stand up and continue your prayer to make up the missed *rakahs*.

Comment: @Uma : Appreciate your lucid explanation. I follow the same procedure, but i wanted to make sure. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You come to masjid, and you see that Imam is in ruku, so you stand up-right with others, say "Allahu Akbar" and hold your hands (like you do when starting the prayer), then if Imam is still in ruku then you say Allahu akbar and go to ruku to join all others, then you were able to say "subhanaRabbi al-adeem" at least once before Imam and others come out of ruku  -- then that would mean you have caught the raka. This is fine even if you did not say Al-Fatiha and all the other things that you normally say. This is based on saheeh hadiths.

For more with hadith reference: https://islamqa.info/en/45494

Then count how many rukus you were able to do with the Imam and do the rest of the rakah as usual after Imam finishes the prayer with salam.

For 2-raka prayer you need two rukus, for 3-raka prayer you need 3 rukus and so on.

Comment: islamqa is not known as hanafi site and Op is asking about the hanafi view!

Comment: islamqa has the hadith reference.

Comment: Are hanafi's from the school of hadith?