# What should a person who came late to the salah do if he forgot to make up the missing rakahs?

Tags: salat, jamaat

I came to pray in the mesjid and I missed one rakah and I forgot to pray that one rakah after the imam finished the salah, a few minutes after we finished the salah, I remembered that so I just prayed one rakah (without engaging in lahw, I remember I only made Dhikr and sat leaning on the wall). Is this valid?

Comment: What you exactly mean is not really clear to me. But it looks like [What is the exact manner to join jamat after arriving late](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/what-is-the-exact-manner-to-join-the-salat-jamat-after-arriving-late) is relevant. You should specify whether or not you interrupted the prayer before praying this "additional" rak'ah.

Comment: Edited the question, jazak Allah khayran