# Salah related Question

Tags: salat, tashahhud

If I miss one or more rakah with imam, and I need to complete it after tasleem of imam, in the last sitting of prayer with imam, should I recite only tashahud, or all tashahud, durood and dua ma'surah as well? Please answer with reference.

Comment: Please explain what you mean what is Tashahood only, durood and du'a ma'surah there's only tashahud which should be done and it usually contains as-Salat al Ibrahimiyah (whish Urdu speakers aprently call durood) and some du'a why do you make a difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the exact manner to join the Salat Jamat after arriving late?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/what-is-the-exact-manner-to-join-the-salat-jamat-after-arriving-late)